# Dirac spinors vs. Wigner classification

Tags: particle-physics, field-theory, representation-theory, dirac-equation, antimatter

As I understand, from Wigner's classification of particles it follows that for every $m > 0$ and $s \in \left\{ 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{3}{2}, \dots \right\}$ there is an irreducible, unitary representation $\pi_{m,\frac{1}{2}}$ of $\operatorname{SL}_{\mathbb{C}}(2)$ (the double cover of the connected component of the identity of the Poincaré group) which corresponds to a particle of mass $m$ and spin $\frac{1}{2}$. This representation can be realised with the Hilbert space $\operatorname{L}^2(X_m^+, \sigma) \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$, where $X_m^+$ is the mass shell of mass $m$ in Minkowski space and $\sigma$ the invariant measure on $X^+_m$. Here the double cover of $\operatorname{SO}(3)$, namely $\operatorname{SU}(2)$, acts on the $\mathbb{C}^2$-factor giving rise to spin.

But in QFT texts, when it comes to modelling an electron, instead 4-component wave functions are considered, i.e. the space $\operatorname{L}^2(X_m^+, \sigma) \otimes \mathbb{C}^4$. Here are my questions:

1. Am I correct in assuming that the corresponding representation will be $\pi_{m,\frac{1}{2}} \oplus \pi_{m,\frac{1}{2}}$, where we identify $$ \operatorname{L}^2(X_m^+, \sigma) \otimes \mathbb{C}^4 \cong \operatorname{L}^2(X_m^+, \sigma) \otimes \left( \mathbb{C}^2 \oplus \mathbb{C}^2 \right) \cong \left( \operatorname{L}^2(X_m^+, \sigma) \otimes \mathbb{C}^2 \right) \oplus \left( \operatorname{L}^2(X_m^+, \sigma) \otimes \mathbb{C}^2 \right)? $$
2. Doesn't this somehow break with the mantra that irreducible, unitary representations of the Poincaré group correspond to particles? Since now the representation corresponding to the electron is reducible?
3. Or is this reconciled by somehow interpreting the two summands of the representation as corresponding to an electron and an anti-electron (the positron)? So in theory the Wigner classification would make an anaylsis of the electron in itself possible (by means of the Hilbert space $\operatorname{L}^2(X_m^+, \sigma) \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$), but for other physical reasons this analysis is not complete without adding the second summand corresponding to the positron?
4. And now finally, if the above points are correct, is there a more systematic way of arriving at Dirac spinors from the Wigner classification without resorting to the argument of “to take the square root of the relativistic squared Hamiltonian, one needs $\gamma$-matrices”?